# Obtener un arraylist de objetos que implementan una intefaz java

Tags: java, arraylist, interfaz

Estoy implementando un método:

```
public List<Item> getMovableItems()
```

Con el lo que quiero es recuperar una lista de mis items que implementan la interfaz Movable, solo los que tienen esa interfaz.

De primeras he creado una lista (será la que retorne)

```
List<Item> MovableItems = getItems();
```

Esta lista ya tiene todos los objetos de tipo item que vaya instanciando, pero solo quiero los que implementan `Movable` y no se como puedo recuperarlo.

Estoy intentando con un bucle for recorrer la lista para descartar los items que no tengan `Movable` pero no se bien como hacerlo.

A alguno se lo ocurre como puedo hacerlo?¿ Soy nuevo en java y voy bastante perdido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para preguntar si tu clase tiene la instancia, puedes utilizar [el operador instanceof](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/javadoc/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html)

> Este operador te dice si un objeto pertenece a una clase determinada.

Para tu caso en particular:

```
List MovableItems = getItems();
ArrayList<Movable> MovableItemsOk = new ArrayList<Movable>();

for(int i = 0; i < MovableItems.size(); i++) 
{
    //aquí comprobamos si el objeto implementa la clase Movable
    if (MovableItems.get(i) instanceof Movable) 
    {
        //En el caso de serlo, imprimimos el mensaje y lo añadimos a una nueva lista
        System.out.println("El elemento " + i + " Es Movable");
        MovableItemsOk.add(MovableItems.get(i));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("El elemento " + i + " no es Movable");
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Me ha servido. Saludos!

Comment: @David1717 si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada y considera darle un +1.